# JQuery Selector To Remove Children From Collection, By Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably an easy question and I'll feel foolish when I see the answer, but I'm not a javascript expert and I've been struggling with it for a while. The question is based on a modification I am trying to make to [this jQuery plugin HTML-table-to-Excel export library](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel).

The library excludes table rows where the `<tr>` tag has a particular class. However, I want to add functionality so it will remove other child elements that have that class, without removing the whole row (the underlying issue is that I have buttons in a table cell that make sense in a web browser, but not in Excel). Here is the problem in essential form.

HTML:

```
<div id="test-div">
<b>Original Table</b>
<table id="test-table">
<tr class="exclude"><td>Exclude this row</td></tr> <!-- this works fine-->
<tr><td>Include this whole row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Include this row <span class="exclude">but not this text</span></td>  </tr>
</table>
    <hr />
    <b>Modified Table</b> <!-- is inserted by jQuery below -->  
</div>
```

and Jquery:

```
$("#test-div").append("<table>");
$("#test-table").find("tr").not(".exclude").each(function (i,o) {
$("#test-div").append("<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>"); //  <-- how to exclude child span of class "exclude" from this tr? 
   }); 
$("#test-div").append("</table>");
```

Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9pq9dza/2/). The goal is to get the text "but not this span" to not appear in the Modified Table (i.e., what's being exported), without altering the original table (which the user is viewing). It should also work if the span were a more distant child, or if it were another tag type (e.g., if it went `<tr><td><div><div class="exclude">`, that div should be excluded also). I've tried chaining various other .not() methods, or trying not:() selectors on another find(), but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ryosh/ezu026vs/)?

```
<div id="test-div">
    <b>Original Table</b>
    <table id="test-table">
    <tr class="exclude"><td>Exclude this row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Include this whole row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Include this row <span class="exclude">but not this text</span></td></tr>
</table>
    <hr />
     <b id="new-table">Modified Table</b>

</div>
```

Jquery

```
var newTable = $("#test-table").clone();
newTable.appendTo("#new-table").html();
$("#new-table  *").remove(".exclude");
```

Comment: I was previously thinking I couldn't use methods like .remove(.selector) since I didn't want to modify the DOM, but with .clone() that doesn't matter since I'm working with the clone, not the DOM the user is seeing. Thanks.